# ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage , I use WKWebView but not work

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

[image]

I want to solve ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage when cordova build ios
I use WKWebView to replace UIWebView but not work

Comment: what Cordova version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using pod, then follow below steps to resolve.

In `Podfile`, Remove all pods line and `pod install`

Again add all latest pods and `pod install`.

The problem will be solved. Xcode doesn't update all files when pod update

I spent lot of time & found this. This may be useful to you...